# parse json data coming from webservice in java

Tags: java, json, web-services

I am developing android app where I am getting web-service data as:

```
"[{\"ID\":51,\"Text\":\"!! SAMPLE PROJECT !!\"},{\"ID\":58,\"Text\":\"01 Contracting Test Project\"},{\"ID\":64,\"Text\":\"1212\"},{\"ID\":45,\"Text\":\"CHEMICAL FACTORY PROJECT\"}]"
```

Now I want to parse this data in json I used replaceAll() function to replace backslashes from the string like this:

```
 String jsonFormattedString = line.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

But I think this method isnot good to work with because it removes all the backslashes from the string which creates problems like I recieved json node like:

```
"[{\"ID\":9617,\"Text\":\"1 1\/4\\\" PVC\/GI CLAMPS\"}]"
```

where the string value for Text contains double quotes within string which creates problem for me. So my question is what is the best way to parse this json data in java.

My full json data returned by webservice is as:

```
"[{\"ID\":51,\"Text\":\"!! SAMPLE PROJECT !!\"},{\"ID\":58,\"Text\":\"01 Contracting Test Project\"},{\"ID\":64,\"Text\":\"1212\"},{\"ID\":45,\"Text\":\"CHEMICAL FACTORY PROJECT\"},{\"ID\":53,\"Text\":\"Kanix City\"},{\"ID\":54,\"Text\":\"KANIX DREAM CITY\"},{\"ID\":59,\"Text\":\"KANIX DREAM CITY -- PHASE II\"},{\"ID\":62,\"Text\":\"KANIX DREAM CITY PHASE I\"},{\"ID\":55,\"Text\":\"Kishor_TEST\"},{\"ID\":63,\"Text\":\"Next Generation Housing\"},{\"ID\":65,\"Text\":\"Nothing Job\"},{\"ID\":56,\"Text\":\"PAVAN_TEST\"},{\"ID\":46,\"Text\":\"PRODUCTION UNITS\"},{\"ID\":1,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-01(TYPE 1)\"},{\"ID\":3,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-02(TYPE 1)\"},{\"ID\":5,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-03(TYPE 1)\"},{\"ID\":6,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-04(TYPE 1)\"},{\"ID\":7,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-05(TYPE 1)\"},{\"ID\":8,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-06(TYPE 1)\"},{\"ID\":2,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-07(TYPE 2)\"},{\"ID\":4,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-08(TYPE 2)\"},{\"ID\":9,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-09(TYPE 3)\"},{\"ID\":10,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-10(TYPE 3)\"},{\"ID\":11,\"Text\":\"PROJECT-11(TYPE 4)\"},{\"ID\":57,\"Text\":\"Reviera Classic\"},{\"ID\":43,\"Text\":\"ROAD PROJECT\"},{\"ID\":41,\"Text\":\"SAMPLE PROJECT 1\"},{\"ID\":42,\"Text\":\"SAMPLE PROJECT 2\"},{\"ID\":52,\"Text\":\"Shailesh Test project@1000\"},{\"ID\":61,\"Text\":\"VISHAL PARADISE\"},{\"ID\":60,\"Text\":\"WTC\"}]"
```

my full code is like this:

```
@Override
protected List<CItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
    String line="";
    String ur = "http://"+ServerDetails.hostServer+"/appservices.svc/Projects?Keyword=" ;

       lstItm=new ArrayList<CItem>() ;


        // Replace it with your own WCF service path
        URL json = new URL(ur);
        URLConnection jc = json.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));

         line = reader.readLine();
         Log.d("LINE",line);
           JSONArray array=new JSONArray(line);


        Itm=new CItem( "-1", "Select Project" );
        lstItm.add(Itm);
        for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject tmpJson=array.getJSONObject(i);


            Itm=new CItem(tmpJson.getString("ID"),tmpJson.getString("Text"));
            lstItm.add(Itm);


        }


        return  lstItm ;






    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("ERRROR--->",e.getMessage());



    }





    return  lstItm ;

}
```

Comment: Use a predefined library like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Answer (score 1):

@mubu9082 ..you dont need to remove these backslashes...
as this json string is shown with backslashes in log or by debugger..

just parse it as usual

```
public void jsonParser()
{
    ArrayList<> list=new ArrayList<>(); //declare this as global
    String responseString="[{\"ID\":51,\"Text\":\"!! SAMPLE PROJECT !!\"},{\"ID\":58,\"Text\":\"01 Contracting Test Project\"},{\"ID\":64,\"Text\":\"1212\"},{\"ID\":45,\"Text\":\"CHEMICAL FACTORY PROJECT\"}]";
    JSONArray array=new JSONArray(responseString);
    String id[]=new String[array.length()];
    String text[]=new String[array.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
    {
         JSONObject tmpJson=array.getJSONObject(i);
         id[i]=tmpJson.getString("ID");
         text[i]=tmpJson.getString("TEXT");
         CItem Itm=new CItem(tmpJson.getString("ID"),tmpJson.getString("Text")); lstItm.add(Itm);
         list.add(Itm);
    }
}
```

do this to get response from server

```
try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the given URL ...use
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response as inputStream
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        String response= EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        //pass this response to JSONArray object
        //save response and then flush the entity.
        entity.consumeContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

pass this response to JSONArray object

Comment: after using your code I got exception like this:          05-15 11:46:52.158    2821-2841/kanix.highrise.com.highrise D/ERRROR--->﹕ Value [{"ID":51,"Text":"!! SAMPLE PROJECT !!"},{"ID":58,"Text":"01 Contracting Test Project"},{"ID":64,"Text":"1212"},{"ID":45,"Text":"CHEMICAL FACTORY PROJECT"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: strange... i've run the same code from this editor to my android-studio..and its working properly...

Comment: there is something wrong with responseString...have u tried putting the static value for responseString as i set ?

Comment: line = reader.readLine();

              JSONArray array=new JSONArray(line);


            Itm=new CItem( "-1", "Select Project" );
            lstItm.add(Itm);
            for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject tmpJson=array.getJSONObject(i);


                Itm=new CItem(tmpJson.getString("ID"),tmpJson.getString("Text"));
                lstItm.add(Itm);


            }

         
            return  lstItm ;






        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("ERRROR--->",e.getMessage());



        }

Comment: I used above code. please see if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: @mubu9082 ..i suggest you to edit your question with this logic or any work regard you question ...so its better for others to..

Comment: how you get json response ... ? this part too

Comment: please check my edit question where I have shown full json string returned by webservice

Comment: strange when I use full data as a hard coded it works fine but when I use it as a response from web-service it generates exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77863/discussion-between-mubu9082-and-angad-tiwari).

Answer (score 0):

```
public InsuranceDO getInsuranceData1(Context context) {

    String urlStr = "http://192.168.2.11:8080/Service/category/sample";
    InsuranceDO insuranceDO = new InsuranceDO();
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    List<InsuranceDO> insList = new ArrayList<InsuranceDO>();
    try {
        String reqVal = "T=421D84EAC8DEB4878CE48C8A0CB870791EB96FE51C7800A8806032A8CE69A4966D87FFA2E139EE6586C1924F9BD070154CB7E8F92985AC6674B0AD37D9F3FC1ED7B2E4C2D01E5525DCE5E6FCDA26AF890633011894AA2B72604CC8B046E4F9C37DE9A61EECD7000325D3EC673E8609AAD753C52B9BC002C014BC18A35AA8AB3636C237088A08EEED72A7C5F2EDE60155E9111A6F74F082C0E4B45D484C00CA5AD5B3560B8A10D47616E48077EBDE490E&UserCode=172278&DBSource=bali";
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(reqVal.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        /**
         * To parse json to list data
         */
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            insuranceDO.setAgeing(jsonObject.getString("xxx"));
            insuranceDO.setInsuredName(jsonObject.getString("yyyy"));
            insuranceDO.setProposalNumber(jsonObject.getString("zzzz"));
            insuranceDO.setReason(jsonObject.getString("aaaa"));
            insList.add(insuranceDO);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, insList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return insuranceDO;
}
```